# Filtering Drupal vocabularies

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy

Apologies if this is a duplication - I'm a total newbie to Drupal and there's a fair chance I've read the answer to my question and just not realized it.

I have a simple vocabulary with 2 tiers. Structure is:

Canton
-Town

So looks like:

Vaud
-Vevey
-Montreux
Valais
-Sion
-Brig

I am trying to build a form with 2 separate fields as drop down list, 1 for canton and 1 for town, populated from the vocabulary where list 1 has only the cantons (1st tier of vocabulary) and 2nd only has towns (2nd tier) with the relationship to the canton.

Cant figure out how to do it ... after 2 days searching coming here for help.

Any guidance much appreciated